# how to convert ms access .mdb to .accdb using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

how to convert ms access .mdb to .accdb using VBA

Answer (score 2):

Use `ConvertAccessProject`

```
Sub ConvertToACCDB()
  Dim src  As String
  Dim dst As String
  
  src = "c:\csnet\file.mdb"
  dst = "c:\csnet\file.accdb"
  
  ConvertAccessProject src, dst, AcFileFormat.acFileFormatAccess2007

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for your support.